# Oracle APEX - ORA-01722: invalid number when saving Interactive report/Interactive grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, ora-01722, interactive-grid

While trying to create new Interactive Grids or Interactive Reports in APEX applications, everything works as expected until the SAVE button is clicked and the following error message is displayed:

ORA-01722: invalid number

The problem appears to be only with Save but not with the query during runtime.

I'm using Oracle APEX 22.2.0.

So there isn't problem with query. I tried with "select 1 from dual" or any other simple query.
Then I saw suggested answers (2 years ago) and tried using Firefox. An it works.

What can I do to make it work on Chrome and Edge. Is this Oracle issue and it will be fixed with a new version?

Comment: I've never seen such a behavior. Did you (apart from reading *suggested answers*) try to run page in **debug mode** so that you'd see which statement actually raised the error and - possibly - fix it?

Comment: I cannot save page with new interactive grid, so I cannot debug it at the runtime. As I stated in my question, problem occurs even if I put "select 1 from dual" statement.
As it works in Firefox, I doubt it is related to query issue.

Comment: My Oracle Support document 2859399.1 says that it might be due to **language** other than English. Try to append `&p_lang=en` to URL in address bar and see what happens.

Comment: @Littlefoot, actually that's it. I've changed language in Globalization attributes, and now everything works. Thank you very much.
It looks like a bug and not really intuitive. Hope Oracle will fix it in a new release.

Comment: Does that other language use a different number format? E.g. dots instead of commas or vice versa. Then that is your issue.

Comment: Hmm, not really sure. But I tried very simple query in interactive report like "select 1 from dual". And also, on the Firefox it works with different language. Really strange issue :) .